# Android how to select a wireless network by name?

Tags: android

My application uses the WiFi network, it works on a home or mobile wireless network. My problem is network FreeWifi, to connect to FreeWifi requires at préable have validated a username and password on http://wifi.free.fr. When I select FreeWifi as Wifi Network, knowing that I did not register on their site says the tablet, connected, and by executing my application with this network, the app stops.What should I do? thank you

Comment: Open web browser and log in first. Android will usually show a 'Sign in to the WiFi network' notification.

Comment: I try to do this                                                                                                                               @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      //
      if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
       if (wifiInfo.getSSID().equals("FreeWifi")) { 
   ?
  }else {....

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem that I wanted to get around through it, if I had my problem was solved. It was necessary that my application connects to google store to download another apppplication, I used `PackageManager`.